# Substracting char* in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, char

I am reading through this blog post: https://nee.lv/2021/02/28/How-I-cut-GTA-Online-loading-times-by-70/

I am confused on how:

```
size_t len = end - str;
```

If I am correct, strings in C are represented as arrays and C strings have pointers to the first element of that array. So is that above line playing with array subscripts?

They posts these lines:

```
size_t strlen_cacher(char *str) {
    static char *start;
    static char *end;
    size_t len;
    const size_t cap = 20000;

    // if we have a "cached" string and current pointer is within it
    if (start && str >= start && str <= end) {
        // calculate the new strlen
        len = end - str;

        // if we're near the end, unload self
        // we don't want to mess something else up
        if (len < cap / 2)
            MH_DisableHook((LPVOID)strlen_addr);

        // super-fast return!
        return len;
    }

    // count the actual length
    // we need at least one measurement of the large JSON
    // or normal strlen for other strings
    len = builtin_strlen(str);

    // if it was the really long string
    // save it's start and end addresses
    if (len > cap) {
        start = str;
        end = str + len;
    }

    // slow, boring return
    return len;
}
```

Comment: The `static char* end;` has been initialised beyond the `0` initialisation that a `static` variable is given. So the pointer arithmetic `len = end - str;` is undefined behaviour because such arithmetic is only valid when the pointers are to the same object (or one element beyond).

Comment: But pointer arithmetic works in *units of the object type*. In the same way that array indexing is also in units of the object type. So with `len = end - str;` if `end` points to the nul terminator then `len` will be the length of the string.

Comment: @WeatherVane The `if (start ...)` makes sure that `start` and `end` are initialized by the "slow" code before they are used in the "fast" code. The code is not great, I agree.

Comment: @user3386109 yes I noticed that but at first sight...

Comment: The code does not contain the claimed size_t len = char* str - char* end, the subtraction is the other way round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume the code is correct and `end` is a pointer to the string `nul` terminator, *i.e.* the last element of the char array.

This is simple pointer arithmetic. In your example, since you pass the string as an argument, it will decay to a pointer to its first element, subtracting the pointer to the first element of an array from a pointer to any other element of the same array will give you the offset in number of elements between those two pointers, this is true for `char` or for any other type.

As exemplified in the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    char str[] = "hello";

    char *end = str + 5; // will point to the last element of str, the nul byte
                         // in the above expression str will decay 

    printf("%td", end - str); // 5
    // when you pass str to printf, again it decays
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`if (start && str >= start && str <= end) {` is *undefined behavior* (UB) unless `start` and `end` are within the same object that `str` points to.

```
strlen_cacher("Hello");
strlen_cacher("World"); // UB
```

In C it is UB to *compare* with `>, >=, <=, <` unrelated pointers.

---

"He posts these lines:" --> Take care when [importing](//www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/you%20get%20what%20you%20pay%20for) other's code.

Comment: Good catch on *subsequent* call.

Answer (score 1):

This code attempts to accelerate the `strlen` function called repeatedly on large strings by *cacheing* the last large string boundaries and returning the distance from `str` to `end` if `str` is between `start` and `end`. The distance `end - str` is the length of the string if `end` points to the null terminator.

This is risky because:

- the test `str >= start && str <= end` actually has undefined behavior if all pointers do not point to the same array. This test would fail spectacularly on ancient 16-bit segmented architectures where only the offset part was compared for `<`, `<=`, `>` and `>=`.
- this approach assumes that the long string does not change between calls to `strlen_cacher`. This may be true for the game loader in the referenced page, but not true in general. For example calling `strlen` on a long line read by `getline()` and then on each token carved from it by `strtok` will return incorrect results. The patch disables itself after the load phase to avoid this pitfall.